# RxJs - Having trouble resolving observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So I have an NgRx selector that returns an Observable with an array of Contacts. I would like to map over this stream, and for each array of contacts, map over each individual contact and make an Http request to Github to fetch their profile image, and append this to the Contact object. However, I am not sure how to do this without ending up with an Observable of an array of Observables.

Below is what I have tried, but this is not working.

```
this.contacts$: Observable<Contact[]> = this.store.select(getContacts).pipe(
  map(contacts => {
    return contacts.map(contact => {
      return this.contactService.getGithub$(contact._id).pipe(
        map(githubInfo => {
          return {
            ...contact,
            imageUrl: githubInfo.avatar_url
          };
        })
      );
    });
  })
);
```

And below is the error message I am getting:

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<Contact>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Contact[]>'.
  Type 'Observable<Contact>[]' is not assignable to type 'Contact[]'.
    Type 'Observable<Contact>' is missing the following properties from type 'Contact': first_name, last_name, job_title, location, company ts(2322)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `switchMap` to map your `contacts` array to an Observable that simultaneously executes your http requests and maps them to an extended Contact object.

```js
this.contacts$: Observable<Contact[]> = this.store.select(getContacts).pipe(
  switchMap(contacts => forkJoin(
    contacts.map(contact => this.contactService.getGithub$(contact._id).pipe(
      map(gitHubInfo => ({ ...contact, imageUrl: githubInfo.avatar_url }))
    ))
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are running an `Array.map` which returns an Observable for each `contact`. If you want the Observable to return the completed array, you'll want something like this:

```js
this.contacts$: Observable<Contact[]> = this.store.select(getContacts).pipe(
  // take the array and emit each value one by one
  concatMap(contacts => from(contacts)),
  // emit an array containing the contact and the corresponding githubInfo
  concatMap(contact => forkJoin(of(contact), this.contactService.getGithub$(contact._id))),
  // take the returned array and convert it to an Object
  map(([contact, githubInfo]) => ({ ...contact, imageUrl: githubInfo.avatar_url})),
  // concatenate everything into a final Array
  toArray()
);
```

I must admit I've written this on the go, therefore without testing it, but I think it should work!

If maintaining the original order is important, keep `concatMap`. If not, use `mergeMap` to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks, Will! This is pretty close, but for some reason it is not emitting any values. If I remove the toArray(), it does emit individual values with the proper imageUrl attached.

Comment: I believe the stream needs to complete for toArray() to work

Comment: Your selector should complete once it has emitted all its values, no?

Comment: Well it is a memoized selector that will re-emit the array of contacts anytime the NgRx store value changes. So it never really completes. I may be wrong, but I believe that is how it works.

Comment: You're completely correct, sorry! I wasn't thinking in NgRx terms! You have a few possible choices if you really need an Array. You can use scan/reduce strategies, or add a `takeUntil` after extracting the length of the original contacts Array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I figured scan() might be necessary.  I will play around with your suggestions and see if I can get a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose it all depends on how you need this Observable to behave. Instead of splitting things up with the first `concatMap`, you could simply use an `Array.map` for the Observable to emit full Arrays each time. If you only need this to emit once (and not be particularly reactive), you could add a `take(1)` to the beginning of the pipe.

Answer (score -1):

```html
this.contacts$: Observable<Contact[]> = this.store.select(getContacts).pipe( 
    map(contacts => {
        return contacts.map(contact => {
            return this.contactService.getGithub$(contact._id).pipe(
                map(githubInfo => {
                    return { ...contact, imageUrl: githubInfo.avatar_url };
                })
            );
        });
    }),
    concatAll()
);
```

Just add `concatAll` operator to pipe stream.

Comment: Answers with no formatting or explanation are not helpful.